# Using multiple unique constraints in one postgresql table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to write a command which adds a row to my postgreSQL table if two of the columns do not contain the same data else where.  Neither `user_id` nor `venue_id` need to be unique however I do not want to add a new row that has the same `user_id` AND `venue_id` as a previous row.

My table

```
id user_id venue_id like dislike
1   1        1       1    0
2   1        2       0    0
3   2        2       1    1
```

Currently I am trying

```
INSERT INTO user_matches (user_id, venue_id) VALUES (1,1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want a unique index/constraint on  the two columns:

```
alter table user_matches add constraint unq_user_matches_user_venue
    unique (user_id, venue_id);
```

You can then use this constraint for `on conflict`.

Comment: Lindoff, it seems like this will work for single entries however I using a multiple input statement `INSERT INTO user_matches (user_id, venue_id) VALUES (1, 10), (1,20), (1,3);` and I do not want my entire query to fail when just one of the entries is a duplicate.

Comment: @tdammon . . . That is why you use `on conflict ignore`.